# Preserving icon cache in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, icons, cache, desktop-icons

Is it possible to preserve icon cache?

It seems like after shutdown/reboot there is not any cache for icons anymore. E.g. when I turn on PC and go to programs directory that contains many many shourtcuts, It loads a bit of time all these shortcuts and their icons. Next time I open this directory it's instant. But next time i turn on PC it's again a bit of time [loading icons] for the first time going into this directory.

For me it looks like Explorer is rebuilding icons after each PC startup or they are being destroyed after each PC shutdown, or after each PC startup and then building up when operating

The same with all else's icons.

Couldn't found anything on this topic in the internet.

All articles I found was about rebuilding icon cache or fixing broken icon cache.

Windows 10 Pro x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Was having the same issue, Windows 10 Home (64-bit) 1809. According to [this Tutorial](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/103762-prevent-windows-10-deleting-thumbnail-cache.html) posted on the Windows 10 Forums, the issue is related to the way Automatic Maintenance service handles temp files. The article details which registry key to toggle in order to prevent the thumbnail cache from being deleted each time the service runs (before/during/following reboot). They have also provided a simple reg file for those who are not comfortable making edits to the registry. *Be sure to download the file designated "To Prevent Windows 10 from Deleting Thumbnail Cache as part of Automatic Maintenance" and choose 32 or 64-bit accordingly*.

In my case I downloaded the 64-bit version of the reg file and merged it. After reboot checked several folders containing many different file types and icons and instead of watching them slowly reload yet again, this time everything snapped into view just like it always has done on my [still superior] Windows XP machine.

Credit and much thanks to Shawn Brink and the Windows 10 Forums for this helpful solution.

Comment: thx bro! really much